# Passing multiple complex parent actions to deeply nested child views

Tags: elm

Disclaimer: *I realized this was a maybe stupid question after I finished writing it. Please don't spend too much time reading it. I am very new to Elm, functional programming, and not a UI buff.*

I have a view in Elm that returns `Html Msg` and takes in a `model`. Using the simple increment demo as en example, I have this typical setup:

```
module Main exposing (..)
import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
-- MAIN

main =
  Browser.sandbox { init = init, update = update, view = view }

-- MODEL
type alias Model = Int

init : Model
init =
  0

-- UPDATE
type Msg
  = Increment
  | Decrement

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Increment ->
      model + 1

    Decrement ->
      model - 1

-- VIEW

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ button [ onClick Decrement ] [ text "-" ]
    , div [] [ text (String.fromInt model) ]
    , button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
    ]
```

I have a button component that's quite complex which I would like to extract into a separate function. I'm able to do this with normal Html, i.e.

```
-- VIEW
some_html : Html msg
some_html =
  text "FOO"

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ button [ onClick Decrement ] [ text "-" ]
    , div [] [ text (String.fromInt model) ]
    , button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
    , some_html
    ]
```

I can also pass the `Msg` type I've defined and have the "sub-function" call the action:

```
-- VIEW
make_button : Msg -> Html Msg
make_button msg =
  button [ onClick msg ] [ text "-" ]

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ make_button Decrement
    , div [] [ text (String.fromInt model) ]
    , button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
    ]
```

**My problem and question is:**

I would like to be able to have my `make_button` function be able to handle multiple actions. One way I have found that works is to pass all possible actions and then a key, i.e.

```
-- VIEW
make_button : Msg -> Msg -> String -> Html Msg
make_button decr incr which =
  if which == "Decrement" then
  button [ onClick decr ] [ text "-" ]
  else button [ onClick incr ] [ text "+" ]

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ make_button Decrement Increment "Decrement"
    , div [] [ text (String.fromInt model) ]
    , make_button Decrement Increment "Increment" -- doesn't matter here.
    ]
```

But this becomes cumbersome when the number of actions is large (in my use case I have 20 or so actions).

**Should I create a dictionary of sorts? Is there a way this is done? Is this a bad thing to do? Please give me grief.**

I am imaging scenarios where many nested child components might want to have the ability to call any Action of the parent component on the fly without this being hard-coded, which is why I decided to still ask the question.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the hole you are digging for yourself stems from: _"... might want to have the ability to call any Action ..."_ This usually means that you are over-engineering something.

Comment: You might find the following presentations useful for understanding the Elm philosophy of refactoring: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpDsk374LDE and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoA4Txr4GUs

Comment: One thing I'll point out: `Msg`s are globally scoped. You don't need to pass them in as arguments to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely over thinking things! The way you would do this is

```
-- camel case is the convention in Elm ;)
makeButton : Msg -> Html Msg
makeButton msg =
    button
        [ onClick msg ]
        [ text <|
            -- an if statement would also work in this case
            case msg of
                Increment ->
                    "+"

                Decrement ->
                    "-"
        ]


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ makeButton Decrement
        , div [] [ text (String.fromInt model) ]
        , makeButton Increment
        ]
```